# Jquery stoping onchange function on switch case inside other switch case

Tags: javascript, jquery, switch-statement, onchange

I have switch case over a switch case scenario.

When I select the option 1: case 1 and selecting option 2 gives me prompt 'For case 1 Only'.. which is good.

But when I select the option 1: case 2.. the option 2 still run.. which is definitely not.

Can anyone suggest how to correct this.

```
$("#option1").change(function(e){   

    switch(option1) {
     case 1:    
       $("#option2").change(function(e){    
        switch(option2) {

        case 'A':
           alert('For case 1 Only'); 
           break;
        }

       });  
      break;
     case 2:
      //  Some Option 2 scenario

      break;
     default:
     // code to be executed if n is different from case 1 and 2
    }       
 });
```

Comment: Why are you binding event handler inside event handler?

Comment: The logic here hurts my head. What exactly are you trying to do, because I'm sure there's a nicer way of doing it.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/JtFvK/4/  great this is it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently you are binding event handler inside event handler. So Whenever `option1` changes you are binding a event handler to `option2` (I am sure you don't want this).

I think you need this(On assumptions).

```
$("#option1, #option2").change(function(e) {
    var option1 = $('#option1').val();
    var option2 = $('#option2').val();
    switch (option1) {
        case 1:
            switch (option2) {
                case 'A':
                    alert('For case 1 Only');
                    break;
            }
            break;
        case 2:
            break;
        default:
            // code to be executed if n is different from case 1 and 2
    }
});
```